# C# IBM MQ Unmanaged Client Password protection negotiation failed When Connect To Remote Queue

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I managed to connect to my local queue with SSL using the code below. It is an unmanaged client. However, when I connect to a remote queue, I encounter an error

> Password protection negotiation failed.
>
> The channel 'Remote_Queue' could not be established because it
> failed to agree a password protection algorithm with the remote
> machine 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx(5593)'. &P The channel did not start.
>
> Check whether the PasswordProtection attribute in the Channels stanza
> of mqclient.ini prevents interoperability with the remote machine.
> Consider changing the PasswordProtection attribute. &P Alternatively,
> consider using SSL or TLS to protect passwords instead. You must use
> a non-null CipherSpec to protect passwords.

What do I need to look at here? Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System;

namespace MqClientUnmanaged
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            var queueManagerName = "Remote_QM";
            var hostName = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
            var channel = "Remote_Channel";
            var queueName = "Remote_Queue";
            var port = "5593";
            var sslKeyRepository = @"C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\mqdev";
            var cipherSpec = "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384";
            var certLabel = "mqdev";

            Hashtable prop = new Hashtable();
            prop.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            prop.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            prop.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
            prop.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);
            prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);
            prop.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, certLabel);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in prop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
            }

            try
            {
                
                var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, prop);

                MQQueue _queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");

                MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
                MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();

                _queue.Get(retrievedMessage, gmo);                
                Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", retrievedMessage.ReadString(retrievedMessage.MessageLength));
                Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 100));

            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: READ ERROR message!!! See following : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=securing-protecting-passwords-in-mq-component-configuration-files

Comment: Ignore @jdweng, that link is not related to your error.

Comment: @colin are you saying if you do not call queueManager.AccessQueue that you can see the channel in a RUNNING status and only when you call queueManager.AccessQueue it fails.  This seems strange because the password protection is negotiated during channel start up, not when you open a queue.  Also PW protection is negotiated only if the channel is not TLS or is TLS with a NULL cipher.  Can you confirm the full version of the queue manager, the MQ Client and the amqmdnet.dll?

Comment: @JoshMc : Does the password scheme have to be set properly?  Is the password encrypted or not encrypted?  The configuration of the server has to match the c# code.

Comment: @jdweng in this case it is negotiated between the client and the server and can not be set. The password sent to authenticate to MQ is passed by the app in clear text and is encrypted over the network by the TLS cipher (if not a NULL cipher) if TLS is in use or by the negotiated password protection scheme if not TLS or using a NULL TLS cipher. They don't officially publish what is used but in the past IBM has stated it is AES. See [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=mq-mqcsp-password-protection) for more information.

Comment: @jdweng the document you linked to has to do with passwords stored fir the queue manager or related components to use, but related to a user being authenticated to the queue manager.

Comment: The remote queue is set up with a MQIPT

Comment: @JoshMc it says "The PasswordProtection attribute in the Channels section of the client and queue manager .ini configuration files" On the client side, does this mean my C# client application? If YES, where to set this PasswordProtection attribute?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the root cause. I need to do a test. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT37968

Comment: That sounds like your issue.  You could downgrade the client to 9.2.3 or upgrade the MQIPT to 9 2.5 or 9.2.0 4 or higher.   Good catch.   One I'll be on the look out for.

Comment: @JoshMc the issue is resolved now. The MQIPT is v9.2.0.3. After installing MQC v9.2.0.3, my C# client program can connect to the MQIPT and read the message. Thanks all for the input. Appreciate it.